Converting an Excel formula to a VBA macro
recently i have found a formula and modified it and now it works as i want. It is a formula that calculates the difference between two cells with a certain formatting, like this:
Cell I1: (-100-?-?)
Cell J1: 1000
Result: 900
The formatting can vary, the I1 cell is sometimes just (-?) or (-56-200) without no question marks for example, i need to find how much difference there is between I1 and J1. Now my problem is, i want this to run as a macro and show the result in a message box. I have a couple thousand rows like this and having a column with the formula for each one really slows down my computer so just running the macro would be better.
I want to make a button on the column K2 for example and when i press it, that should calculate it based on the values in I2 and J2 and show it in a message box (or an info bubble). How can i achieve this?
Formula below:

=IF(ISERR(SEARCH("(";I2;1));"";J2-SUM((TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(IF(ISERR(SEARCH("~?";I2;1));(MID(I2;LEN(LEFT(I2;SEARCH("(";I2;1)))+1;LEN(I2)-LEN(LEFT(I2;SEARCH("(";I2;1)))-1));(MID(I2;(LEN(LEFT(I2;SEARCH("(";I2;1)))+1);(LEN(LEFT(I2;SEARCH("~?";I2;1))))-(LEN(LEFT(I2;SEARCH("(";I2;1)))+1)-1)));"-";REPT(" ";255));1+(ROW(I:I)-1)*255;255)) & "0")/10))

I am using Office 365 fyi and the formula is probably not efficient but i couldn't really find a way to convert this to a macro on its own, maybe there is an even better way but i don't know.
Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

So if you have thousands of rows, do you want the message box to appear thousands of times, or have thousands of results? Either doesn't seem like a good idea. It may also be a good idea to show us some sample data and the expected results. Most explanations of data sets are never as clear as people think they are.

A VBA macro will more likely be slower than faster. Given that you can just put the formula in 1 cell, then copy that cell, then make a selection by clicking on the 2nd cell and then shift-click on the last cell and paste, and your formula will be on all cells, that is definitely the way to go.

But your formula uses a lot of search and error checking, it can be optimized for faster performance for sure. I would therefor recommend you to post a new question, explain the I1 and J1 cells and ask for a formula to calculate it, to get one that is quick.

@cybernetic.nomad It is only ~5% of those rows that i need to use this calculation, and it is only once for each one. If it was a dynamic thing that was shown at all times that would be better but it's too laggy that way.

@LPChip I tried to optimize with that if statement at the start, if there's that paranthesis format it initiates the formula, i only have this format on relatively small amount of rows. The total amount of rows i have is about 55k, so filling all of them definitely impacts performance, any advices? Thank you both by the way, i hope there is a better way to do this.

Just create the formula for 1 row, then copy/paste it as I stated earlier. 55k rows is not that much. I've worked with sheets that have over 500k of rows, doing the same thing, and an action like this would take abour 3 minutes, but once its done, working with the sheet is fast.

@LPChip Alright, i'll try again with some optimizations and see how it goes, thanks.
